# Association bonus given at both sites - bug or feature?

Tags: discussion, reputation

[Help says](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation):

> If you are an experienced Stack Exchange network user with 200 or more reputation on at least one site, you will receive a starting +100 reputation bonus to get you past basic new user restrictions.

So is it a bug or a feature that it is awarded on the site user has established reputation as well? I mean, when I went to StackOverflow to ask some php-specific questions, I expected to have 101 reputation there, but I must admit reputation boost on Drupal Questions was kind of surprise.

The way it is now - isn't it encouraging users just past 200 rep to create accounts that will never be used, just to get 50% of their current reputation for free?

Comment: When do you think you got the association bonus on Drupal Answers?  There isn't any indication of this in your rep history (http://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/16495/molot?tab=reputation)

Comment: @MPD May 16 - I know, long ago. Just happened to notice it now. 318 daily reputation seemed strange even for my narcissistic mind ;)

Comment: @MPD and it's not only about me: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/13532/neetu-morwani?tab=reputation

Answer (score 2):

From [How does "Reputation" work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work) (emphasis mine)

> You gain reputation when:
>
> - you associate accounts of two or more Stack Exchange network sites, and at least one of those accounts already has 200 or more reputation:
>     **+100 on each site (awarded a maximum of one time per site)**

Comment: Yes, I see that post in meta differs a bit from this site's help on that matter. However, reasoning in help makes more sense to me. And if it's inaccurate, shouldn't it be corrected?